# How to invoke a menu item from code in AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have some custom code in PurchTable "Register" menuitem's clicked method, Now I need to run the Register command from code after a buttons function has been perfomed.

My question is that how can I call the Register command from code ?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `AutoDeclaration` of the `Register` button to Yes.

Then it is straightforward to call `clicked`:

```
 register.clicked();
```

It is not advisable to have large bodies of code in form methods.

[Reference](http://www.packtpub.com/article/technical-best-practices-for-dynamics-ax-shared-and-aot-object-standards):

> The basic concept of three-tier architecture is that forms should be
>   used only for the presentation tier and hence no other code such as
>   business logic should be there on forms. The code placed on forms also
>   reduces their reusability and the ease of further customization; e.g.
>   if you want to develop an enterprise portal, the code written on forms
>   will have to be written again in classes or table methods, etc., which
>   will make the implementation complex.

Answer (score 23):

I see that you're actually trying to execute the clicked() method, but if you want to execute a Menu Item through code, you can do the following:

```
new MenuFunction(menuItemDisplayStr(MyDisplayMenuItem), MenuItemType::Display).run();
```

Of course the code above may be changed to execute different kinds of Menu Items, for example, the code below runs an Output Menu Item:

```
new MenuFunction(menuItemOutputStr(MyOutputMenuItem), MenuItemType::Output).run();
```

And if you need any argument on the Menu Item you're trying to execute, you can pass it with the *Args* class:

```
Args args = new Args();

args.record(myArgumentRecord);

args.caller(this);

new MenuFunction(menuItemOutputStr(MyOutputMenuItem), MenuItemType::Output).run(args);
```

Comment: This will be the recommended solution over auto-declaring the register button. This way the compiler may track changes to the  menuitem.